# Thin sets in free ultrafilters

Tags: logic, set-theory, filters

Let's all a set $A\subseteq \omega$ (where $\omega$ denotes the set of non-negative integers) *thin* if $$\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{0,\ldots,n\}|}{n+1}=0.$$

Is it true that there are [free ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) on $\omega$ containing thin sets, and there are also free ultrafilters on $\omega$ containing *no* thin sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be thin and infinite, let $F$ be the cofinite filter. Then $F\cup\{X\}$ has the fip, so it extends to an ultrafilter.

To avoid all thin sets remember that upper density is subadditive, so the family of upper density zero sets is closed under finite unions, and the family of their complements has the fip and contains $F$ again.